# Could not load type 'System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions' from assembly 'System.Reflection, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection

Here is my default.aspx:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>

    </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

I m new to .net.

When i run below code, it shows error like this,

> Could not load type 'System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions' from assembly 'System.Reflection, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..'

But i already added system.reflection.dll

Still it shows error,.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your solution first

Comment: yes.. already done..

Answer (score 0):

I'm asssuming you are targeting a 4.0 project whereas IntrospectionExtensions was added in 4.5. If you want to add it to a 4.0 project you'll need the version from Mono (that part was opened sourced in .NET I believe

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Reflection/IntrospectionExtensions.cs ).

Note - This namespace is actually in mscorlib and not in System.Reflection library.

There's a post pointing to the Mono portion for it - so try one or the other if you need 4.0, otherwise use 4.5.

[System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions for .NET 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366976/system-reflection-introspectionextensions-for-net-4-0)

Comment: are you using 4.0 or 4.5? Can you use 4.5? I've checked the url, its OK? Not sure why its failing.